# What does $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ means?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the set of all integers modulo $2$. But $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is the set of all polynomials. I am confused what it looks like.

Comment: These are polynomials with Coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So instead of regular coefficients like you would see in (for example) $p(x)=2x-3$, the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: To further expand: typical examples might be $p(x) = x^3 - x$ or $p(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  As everything is congruent to either one or zero in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, we can also write such polynomials without using the minus symbol.  Since $-1 \equiv 1$, we have things like $x^4-x^3+x^2-1$ equal to $x^4+x^3+x^2+1.$